# website not showing when using ssl on mobile but shows on desktop

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have programmed a website which is : [www.shoesbank.org](http://www.shoesbank.org)
I've used following code to redirect to https. It works perfectly on desktop. But when i want to use it on mobile. I get error which says" the site can not be reached". When i remove https redirection, it is shown perfectly. I have spent tones of hours googling for it, but i found no thing. I appreciate your help.
httaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shoesbank.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.shoesbank.org/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(support\.)?abc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

When I config my apache server, I prefer to handle https in the apache config instead of in the .htacces.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName shoesbank.org
   ServerAlias www.shoesbank.org
   Redirect / https://shoesbank.org
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerAdmin contact@shoesbank.org
   DocumentRoot /var/www/shoesbank.org/public_html/
   ServerName shoesbank.org
   ServerAlias www.shoesbank.org

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/shoesbank.org.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/shoesbank.org.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/shoesbank.org.ca-bundle
  <Directory /var/www/shoesbank.org/public_html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully It works.

Comment: This is a shared hosting. The only access i have is htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe you want to check this article https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9770/38/how-to-use-htaccess-to-redirect-to-https-in-cpanel. And if I am not mistaken usually cpanel got a setting to do forceSSL. CMIIW